# How to move an entire row from one sheet to another based on the date in a certain column AND a selection in another column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have successfully moved an entire row to my "Archive" sheet, but NOT with the criteria mentioned in the title and I have been messing with it for about two or three weeks. I want to be able to archive an entire row that is 30 days old AND has a value of "Complete". I've been trying to successfully incorporate an `onOpen` script but any suggestions would be appreciated if there is another way.

Here is the `onEdit` script that I am working off of and that I've used successfully before (minus the criteria that I want to set in place). I have edited it with `onOpen` before and didn't have any errors but it just wouldn't work.

The checklist sheet is what I'd be pulling my row from, The "Archive" sheet is my destination for the moving of the row and the column 15 is obviously where I'd find my value "Complete". I can give you access to my test sheet if necessary.

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Needed
  // target sheet of move to named Acquired
  // test column with yes/no is col 4 or D
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Checklist" && r.getColumn() == 15 && r.getValue() == "Complete") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created an example spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kl70A_x5qf3wxbxdOwfxletlbnCXnpzDDALaniZjtjs/edit?usp=sharing) with all the apps script to complete your task; just make a copy to play with it. There is a portion of the spreadsheet on Sheet3 that calculates an index for how many rows need to be archived which is needed for the script, sorry I'm fairly new to this so maybe someone else can edit my script to include it.

The formula I am using to get the index for records that need to be archived is:

`=COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet1!A:A<TODAY()-30,Sheet1!B:B="Complete")))`

This script:

1. On opening the spreadsheet runs the following steps:
2. Sorts first 2 columns in sheet1 to bring the completed rows to the top.
3. Uses the index on Sheet3 to move dates older than 30 days to Sheet2.
4. Erased dates older than 30 days off of Sheet1
5. Sorts both columns on Sheet1 back in order by date.

Note: Another option to trigger this script is by changing the function name, going to the [image] icon in the menu, adding a new trigger, and setting it to Function > From spreadsheet > On open

```js
    function onOpen() {
      var s1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
      var s2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2');
      var s3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet3');

      var sortRange = s1.getRange(1, 1, s1.getMaxRows(), 2);

        sortRange.sort([{column: 2, ascending: true}, //first column to sort 
        {column: 1, ascending: true}]);//second column to sort

      var lastDateIndex = s3.getSheetValues(3, 2, 1, 1); //number of rows to move

      var range = s1.getRange(1, 1, lastDateIndex, 2)
        startRow = range.getRowIndex(),
        numRows = range.getNumRows(),
        numCols = range.getNumColumns()


      var values = range.getValues(),
        lastRow = s2.getLastRow();

        s2.getRange(lastRow+1,1,lastDateIndex,2).setValues(values);
        s1.deleteRows(startRow,numRows);

      var sortRange = s1.getRange(1, 1, s1.getMaxRows(), 2); 

        sortRange.sort([{column: 1, ascending: true}]);

     }
```

Comment: I will give it a shot, I appreciate your detailed response and will get back to you as soon as I'm not busy with work.